# Дерево из таблицы

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм, сортировка

Есть таблица вида id, name, parent_name. Как по ней построить дерево, или хотя бы отсортировать по иерархии сверху-вниз? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы бы уточнили, что именно вы хотите, на каком языке программирования, например. Просто если, например, говорить в самом общем виде, то тут применима топологическая сортировка.

Comment: Вопрос странный. Создаете корневой элемент root у которого  name = parent_name. Потом к нему добавляете child'ов у child parent_name = name его предка.

Comment: @Harry алгоритм можно реализовать на любом языке

Comment: @koks_rs на таком уровне я и сам представляю, как это должно быть, но алгоритма придумать не могу

Comment: лучше бы был parent_id вместо parent_name.А алгоритм простой.  Загружаются корни - это у которых parent_name == null. Потом для каждого корня грузятся узлы. Рекурсивно проще, но надо остерегаться большой глубины. А циклов в базе остерегать надо в любом случае.

Comment: @Sergey ну а еще лучше если бы таблица отсортированная сразу шла

Comment: Реализовать можно. Но что вас устроит? Исходник на C++, например? Или средствами SQL? Или что? Если вы в состоянии написать сами - то один из возможных вариантов - для сортировки - я вам подсказал.

Comment: Не всякая база умеет делать рекурсивные запросы. Вот mysql например не умеет. Поэтому там и сортировать нечего. А есть базы c поддержкой recursive cte, Из них можно сразу извлечь отсортированное как надо. Но сам запрос даже простейший не каждый составит с ходу, а думать надо ещё над своими проблемами

Comment: ну если это так важно, то c#, таблицу достаю с помощью Entity Framework

Comment: Entity Framework конечно прикольная штука. Но что там на счёт рекурсивных запросов, А вариант в первом моём коменте делает легко. Да там даже ничего и делать не надо. Взяли корень, а остальное само вытянется. Нормально для связи используют id и parent_id, Редактор модели сам связь обнаружит. Будет сущность с полем-родителем и полем-списком детей. Вот вам ваше дерево

Comment: @Sergey вариант конечно хороший, но имеется только такая таблица.

Comment: Ничто не мешает таблице ссылаться на саму себя. И соответственно entity в полях ссылаться на entity такого же класса. Совершенно штатная ситуация.

Comment: @Sergey нет, вы не поняли. Таблица уже есть, и она имеет поле parent_name, не id, с этим ничего не поделать.

Comment: Попробуйте установить связь по name и parent_name. Если что в ручном режиме.

Comment: @Sergey сделал по именам, дерево получилось) Оформите это как ответ, отмечу правильным, если карма важна)

Comment: Спасибо, не нужна. Сами можете заработать, оформив ответ даже на свой вопрос, наверно. точно не знаю

Answer (score 1):

Иерархию в SQL можно организовывать множеством методов. Один из простых - добавления поля пути http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2004/08/05/hierarchical_sql.html